# How can i avoid duplicating code when writing an interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I want to write a polyline class which needs the functionality from the line and the circular arc class.  I know that a polyline *has* lines and circular arcs therefore i should use an interface instead of extending (i know you can't extend two classes).  The problem is that i will need to write code for the line and the circular arc classes as well and i want to avoid duplicating this code in the polyline class if possible.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is a snippet of code from the line class.  The polyline class also needs to have the getMidPoint(), containsPoint(x,y) etc.  I haven't written the code for circular arc yet but that will have similar functionality getMidPoint(), containsPoint(x,y).

```
public Line (double x1,double y1, double x2,double y2){
    super (x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
public ACSPoint getMidPoint(){
    ACSPoint p = new ACSPoint();
    p.x((this.start.x()+this.end.x())/2);
    p.y((this.start.y()+this.end.y())/2);
    return p;
}
@Override
public boolean containsPoint(double x, double y){
    boolean containsPoint = super.containsPoint(x, y);
    if (containsPoint){
        if (x<this.start.x()||x>this.end.x()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return containsPoint;
}
@Override
public boolean containsPoint(ACSPoint p){
    return this.containsPoint(p.x(), p.y());
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of your intended code?

Comment: Interfaces enforce contracts at compile time (so a class implementing an interface will have an implementation of that interface).  I don't quite understand your question from the description alone; could you provide a model of what your classes look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java doesn't support inheritance from multiple classes, you can use [Object Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Then, the `PolyLine` class will

- implement Line and Arc interfaces
- be composed of Line and Arc implementations.
- delegate the calls to methods in line and arc interfaces to the corresponding objects.

The downside of this is that your PolyLine is tied to one implementation of Line or Arc interfaces. You can prevent that by allowing them to be set during construction. In a typical DI environment, the implementations will get injected or located instead of hard-wiring them.

- Line: Interface and implementation:

  ```
  // Interface: Line.java
  public interface Line
  {
      void lineMethod();
  }

  // Implementation: DefaultLine.java
  public class DefaultLine implements Line
  {
      public void lineMethod()
      {

      }
  }
  ```
- Arc: Interface and implementation

  ```
  // Interface: Arc.java
  public interface Arc
  {
      void arcMethod();
  }

  // Implementation: DefaultArc.java
  public class DefaultArc implements Arc
  {
      public void arcMethod()
      {

      }
  }
  ```
- PolyLine: Interface and implementation where the implementation of Line and Arc hard-wired:

  ```
  public interface PolyLine extends Line, Arc
  {

  }

  public class DefaultPolyLine implements PolyLine
  {
      private Line line;
      private Arc arc;

      public DefaultPolyLine()
      {
          line = new DefaultLine();
          arc = new DefaultArc();
      }

      public void lineMethod()
      {
          line.lineMethod();
      }

      public void arcMethod()
      {
          arc.arcMethod();
      }
  }
  ```
- PolyLine implementation where the Line and Arc implementations are set during construction:

  ```
  public class DefaultPolyLine implements PolyLine
  {
      private Line line;
      private Arc arc;

      public DefaultPolyLine(Line line, Arc arc)
      {
          this.line = line;
          this.arc = arc;
      }

      public void lineMethod()
      {
          line.lineMethod();
      }

      public void arcMethod()
      {
          arc.arcMethod();
      }
  }
  ```

The last implementation of `PolyLine` allows the client to set any Line implementation instead of always using the `DefaultLine` implementation and the same applies for Arc as well.

Comment: I accepted your answer but can you please explain what you mean by "set during construction".   Thanks

Comment: Something interesting to note: if you wait to until Java 8 is released, it supports implemented methods in interfaces, a kind of multiple inheritance ;)